# Google Map GroundOverlay set map bounds, zoom and center of image bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a groundoverlay to set an image on a map but need the map to use my groundoverlay as the center of map and zoom to fit the whole ground overlay on map and center on groundoverlay. Anyone have a solution for this? Been looking for a while.

Example fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/qvLe3xua/18/

My js code

```
    // This example uses a GroundOverlay to place an image on the map
// showing an antique map of Newark, NJ.

var historicalOverlay;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    maxZoom: 17,
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: {lat: 29.76786111111111, lng: -95.45805833333334},
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "weight": "0.50"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#9c9c9c"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.government",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.school",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#eeeeee"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#7b7b7b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    }
]
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 29.770291666666665,
    south: 29.765483333333332,
    east: -95.4573388888889,
    west: -95.46150555555556
  };
  var overlayOpts = {
      opacity:1.0
  };

  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'http://www.houstonian.com/resources/1/CampMap-Rotated2.png',
      imageBounds,overlayOpts);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: I believe `map.fitBounds(imageBounds, 0);` should work. Have you tried this?